Unexpected fee payment during a provisional patent applicaiton
I've come to the last step of online filing a provisional US patent as a "small" not "micro" entity.  The fee payment page lists fees as:
2005 PROVISIONAL APPLICATION FILING FEE $120.00
2091 SUBMISSION OF SEQUENCE LISTINGS OF 300MB TO 800MB $424.00
2092 SUBMISSION OF SEQUENCE LISTINGS OF MORE THAN 800 MB $4,200.0

I have no genetic sequences, just one line drawing, two black & white photographs, and two pages of description.
Is anything wrong with how the submission was made to result in these fee lines, and can I just not pay these two fees?

It is likely an error was introduced in the process. I would call the USPTO’s Electronic Business Center.

